# Thesis using Momentum strategies in R, tips on good books, guidelines etc on how to do the programming?

Tags: time-series, equities, r, programming, momentum

I am quite new to R and will be doing an empirical analysis of momentum strategies in R using a dataset from the index OSEAX from 1980 to 2014. The momentum strategy will for the most part resemble Titman (1993) where we go long on the 30% top performing assets for a given horizon and short the 30% losing stocks.

So far I have found this resource (part 1-5): 
https://rbresearch.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/momentum-with-r-part-1/

Any good R specific finance books og other resources that might help?

Comment: I have looked at all books. Although they not directly go into momentum trading, they present a lot of useful material. Thank you guys!

Comment: Great! Please up vote the answer you like (and optionally accept one as 'the answer',

Comment: Share the thesis when you finish!

Comment: Have a look at the Carhart four factor model. What's the research question? Are to trying to evidence momentum in the Norwegian market?  In that case you're sample might be a bit small enough I wonder if all the data is available from 1980? It might be interesting to look at when momentum is profitable, and for what companies. See  Barosso and Santa-Clara / Momentum has its moments. For implementing it in R I would stick to the standard method that sorts stocks in to deciles based on their momentum ranking as in the Carhart model

Answer (score 1):

Introduction to R for Quantitative Finance received a favorable review here: 
http://www.thertrader.com/category/book-review/

Besides finance-specific books, perhaps 'R Cookbook'?

Answer (score 1):

"The Art of R Programming (A Tour of Statistical Software Design)" by Norman Matloff. It has quite high marks on Amazon. Moreover, you can find a legal version of this book on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

This book by Shumway and Stoffer (two Pitt Stats profs) is excellent IMO:
Time Series Analysis and Its Applications: With R Examples (Springer Texts in Statistics): 9781441978646
[http://www.amazon.com/Time-Series-Analysis-Its-Applications/dp/144197864X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/144197864X)

Answer (score 0):

You got material about momentum, you got material  about R ... usual definitions of momentum are not that difficult ... what are you looking for? A programmed back testing script? Go [here](https://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com/) and you find it all.